# Is there a function to create user generated entry spaces in tkinter from which we can get inputs?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Hello Everyone I am a Student developer developing a student database program GUI. I am using Python and tkinter for the same. So in the program i want to get inputs from the user in entry spaces who's number is not same every time. so i want to know that without **hard coding the spaces** how to get those spaces.
The number of spaces will be defined in the start of  the program by the user.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create the widgets in a loop, and save them in a list.

The following example requires that the number of entries be passed in as an argument:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

num_inputs = int(sys.argv[1])
entries = []
for i in range(num_inputs):
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entries.append(entry)
    entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```